# DataContractJsonSerializer repeated member

Tags: json, deserialization

When deserializing, i get this exception, i have checked the feeds and the datamember "played" is not being repeated twice although it does show twice in the http response.

[System.Runtime.Serialization.SerializationException] = {"The data contract type 'PlayerDetailsSeason' cannot be deserialized because the data member 'played' was found more than once in the input."}

I am not sure why its showing up twice in the http response message.

here's the code

```
            var httpRequest = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, requestUrl + ConstructRequestContent(requestParams));

            var httpClient = new HttpClient();
            HttpResponseMessage responseMessage = await httpClient.SendAsync(httpRequest);
            if (responseMessage != null && responseMessage.IsSuccessStatusCode) {
                Stream stream = await responseMessage.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync();

                DataContractJsonSerializer deserializer = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(T));

                string contentresponsestr = await responseMessage.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
```

//upon investigating the contentresponsestr, I can see the memeber "played" has shown up twice. why is it showing twice?

```
                result = (T)deserializer.ReadObject(stream);

            }

            return result;
        } catch (Exception ex) 
        {

            return result;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

ok found out its a feed problem. Strangely, chrome and lot of other json validators dont check for duplicate data members.